# Need help for ValueError: substring not found

Tags: python, nltk, valueerror

I want to make the sentences as the following:

(N(Hace calor.)-(S(De todas formas, no salgo a casa.)))

(N(Además, va a venir Peter.)-(S(Sin embargo, no lo sé a qué hora llegará exactamente.)))

But the program can only gives me the first sentence and gives an error as ValueError: substring not found for the second sentence. Any one can help? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
from nltk import tokenize
sent = 'Hace calor. De todas formas, no salgo a casa. Además, va a venir Peter. Sin embargo, no lo sé a qué hora llegará exactamente.'
Ant = ['De todas formas', 'Sin embargo']
sent = tokenize.sent_tokenize(sent)
for i in sent:
    for DMAnt in Ant:
        if DMAnt in i:
            sent = '(N(' + str(sent[sent.index(i)-1]) + ')-Antithesis-' +'(S(' + str(sent[sent.index(i)]) + '))'
    print(sent)
```

Comment: `sent_tokenize()` returns a list. But then you change it back to a string in the assignment in the loop.

Comment: So on the next iteration, `sent.index(i)` won't work, because `sent` is a string rather than a list of sentences.

Comment: Maybe you just need to use different variables.

Comment: OK, thanks! I think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are changing your `sent`. I recommend creating a new variable, it will solve the issue.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk import tokenize
sent = 'Hace calor. De todas formas, no salgo a casa. Además, va a venir Peter. Sin embargo, no lo sé a qué hora llegará exactamente.'
Ant = ['De todas formas', 'Sin embargo']
sent = tokenize.sent_tokenize(sent)
new=[]
for i in sent:
    for DMAnt in Ant:
        if DMAnt in i:
            new.append('(N(' + str(sent[sent.index(i)-1]) + ')-Antithesis-' +'(S(' + str(sent[sent.index(i)]) + '))')

print(new)
```

Output:

`['(N(Hace calor.)-Antithesis-(S(De todas formas, no salgo a casa.))', '(N(Además, va a venir Peter.)-Antithesis-(S(Sin embargo, no lo sé a qué hora llegará exactamente.))']`

`new` variable will have your desirable output in the form of list.

Comment: I think this is a good idea for what I want to get. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice. Hi, if this answer solved your problem could you please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark on its side? Thanks.